# ¿Como hacer un insert a una tabla N numero de veces sin utilizar WHILE en SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me gustaría hacer un insert a una tabla en SQL-Server y repetirlo N numero de veces sin utilizar WHILE.

Actualmente tengo algo asi:

```
DECLARE @CONTADOR INT;
DECLARE @NUM_DE_INSERTS INT;
SET @CONTADOR = 1;
SET @NUM_DE_INSERTS = 10;

WHILE (@CONTADOR <= @NUM_DE_INSERTS)
BEGIN
   DECLARE @randomID VARCHAR(2);  
   SET @randomID = CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 10) AS VARCHAR(1)) + CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 10) AS VARCHAR(1));  

   INSERT INTO Table(ID, colB, colC, colD)
   SELECT 
      @randomID,
      colB, 
      colC, 
      colD
   FROM #tempTable

   SET @Contador = @Contador + 1; 
END
```

Ademas de hacer el insert N numero de veces, se genera un ID aleatorio (no consecutivo)

¿Es posible hacer esto con recursividad CTE?

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas un CTE para esto, puedes hacer un `insert`/`select`.

Dado que no explicas por qué uses o qué hay en `#tempTable`, te dejo un ejemplo genérico que ya tu adaptarás a tus necesidades:

```
create table #Ejemplo (Aleatorio varchar(2), Dato int);

declare @NumeroFilas int = 10;

insert into #Ejemplo
select   CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 10) AS VARCHAR(1)) + CAST(ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) % 10) AS VARCHAR(1)) aleatorio
       , 10 Dato
  from (select row_number() over (order by (select null)) NumeroFila from sys.all_columns) as Q
 where NumeroFila <= @NumeroFilas


select *
  from #Ejemplo;
```

Resultado:

```
(10 rows affected)
Aleatorio Dato
--------- -----------
69        10
11        10
35        10
30        10
20        10
63        10
16        10
24        10
54        10
67        10

(10 rows affected)


Completion time: 2021-05-06T12:38:07.6724187-06:00
```

En el `select from select` estoy basándome en numerar filas de la *vista* `sys.all_columns`, que suele tener algunos cuantos miles de registros. Verifica en la base de datos de interés. Si resultan ser muy pocos, puedes hacer algún producto cartesiano con otra tabla del sistema, incluso consigo misma, para lograr que esa devuelva suficientes registros para satisfacer el número de registros máximo que esperas generar en cada ejecución.

En una base de datos típica, en SQL Server 2019, yo encuentro por lo menos 10 000 filas en dicha vista. El producto cartesiano de si misma devolvería 100 000 000 de registros, creo que es suficiente para cubrir cualquier necesidad típica que tengas.